Failed to initialize VisionCamera: VisionCamera currently does not work on web
when open on the web. There is a error!
The Error: Failed to initialize VisionCamera: VisionCamera currently does not work on web.

It appears to initialize VisionCamera in the web environment as well.
How to resolve, or How to do without initializing VisionCamera in a web environment?
